# Merging CSS removes CSS3 filters

Tags: css

I am using the ever popular Ultimo theme in 1.8.10. With 'Merge CSS' enabled in the Magento config, all site files are being merged into one file - perfect.

However, I have some important CSS3 properties which are not being included, the custom selector is included, but is empty. Example as below:-

In custommenu.css

```
.brands img {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
  filter: gray;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.brands img: hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

You guessed it, this will allow images to be shown in the menu as grayscale and in full colour when hovered over. Working perfectly in Firebug and Chrome.

However, the generated CSS file completely omits the properties and generates as so:-

```
.brands img {
}
.brands img:hover {
}
```

My question is - why? Is this a known problem for CSS3 in Magento 1.8.10? Is there a solution to this? I wondered if there was a way to 'override' what is and is not merged?

As a possible solution, I have removed the filter properties and just put something simple like 'background: red;' and these changes do merge and display as expected in the frontend, even just 'filter: none;' does not. I have checked my filter code over and over again and cannot foresee any problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function named `beforeMergeCss` in class `Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package` which runs before merging CSS files. This function is configured to replace 'url' and 'import' patterns from the CSS files, as the merged files are stored in media directory and these properties will not work from there.

Your first CSS rule is falling in that condition and therefore you are seeing those changes. Try removing that and your second rule should be able to bypass those filters(I'm not good in regexes, so you might have to figure out exact behavior yourself).

You can try to override the function or if you understand regexes, you can come up with some rule that easily passes through it.